# How do I use these elements across all of my activities without copy/pasting?

Tags: android, android-studio, view

This is the toolbar I want to have at the bottom of most of my activities. Basically, it is a total of four button images that are in a linear layout. This toolbar is used to move between the four root activities. How do I have this exact set of views on all of my activities so that I do not have to copy paste and mess with id's, etc.?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Android already has a tablayout you should use](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use tab activity or fragment.

You have a main activity in which your desired toolbar is at the bottom of it.

Then by each click on toolbar items, only the container view changes.